# Difference between codeActionsOnSave and formatOnSave in VS Code

Tags: typescript, eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

Newer versions of VS code include a new `codeActionsOnSave` options. It is recommanded to setup Eslint for example. However I don't understand the difference with previously existing `formatOnSave` option, nor their relationship with the `defaultFormater` option, plugins like Prettier and ESLint, and VS Code default behavior.

"Fix" seems more complete, but disabling "format" will not always format my code on save. I also tend to have conflicts between Eslint and Prettier formatting...

Basically it is unclear to me how to set a proper VS Code formatting configuration, that respects project settings (TypeScript, Eslint, Prettier etc. that can be activated/deactivated depending on the project), due to a lack of understanding about the VS Code settings.

Comment: I'm trying to get my VS Code to run ESLint and Prettier together properly as well. I believe formatOnSave runs after codeActionsOnSave from my testing.

Comment: This thread has some good context on the distinction https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87096

Answer (score 41):

> I'm trying to get my VS Code to run ESLint and Prettier together properly as well.

Then [VSCode 1.44 (March 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/71643d75d942e2c32cfd781c2b5322521775fb4a/release-notes/v1_44.md#editor) would highlight another difference between `codeActionsOnSave` and `formatOnSave`:

> ### Explicit ordering for editor.codeActionsOnSave
>
> You can now set `editor.codeActionsOnSave` to an array of code actions to execute in order. You can use this to guarantee that a specific code action is always run before or after another one that may conflict with it
>
> The following `editor.codeActionsOnSave` will always run `Organize Imports` followed by `Fix All` once organize imports finishes:
>
> ```
> "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
>     "source.organizeImports",
>     "source.fixAll"
> ]
> ```

---

But the main difference between `codeActionsOnSave` and `formatOnSave` remains that:

- the latter (`formatOnSave`) only formats code,
- while the former (`codeActionsOnSave`) can run one or several commands on the code, commands which might not be related to formatting.

---

As noted by [Umair Ishaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890304/umair-ishaq) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718493/difference-between-codeactionsonsave-and-formatonsave-in-vs-code/61051832#comment132898063_61051832):

> The actual schema for `editor.codeActionOnSave`, showing it accepts an array, can be found here at [`src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeActions/browser/codeActionsContribution.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9b8548e4479c12e7f6e0e6023b63d660c3906225/src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeActions/browser/codeActionsContribution.ts#L27)

Comment: Where can one find the names of the commands to use in `codeActionsOnSave`? The names of those two actions (as reported by the keyboard shortcut configurator) are `editor.action.organizeImports` and `editor.action.fixAll`, which are different from `source.*`. If we want to add a different command, how can we figure out what it should be called?

Comment: It depends on the plugins involved, as mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/ad85eb71a0d989be6d288d2d36ce2fb131db0ad9/release-notes/v1_23.md. Example: ESLint: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/efa17ec71d755cf14c4722c7d05d10c538cb0e97/release-notes/v1_41.md#eslint. From PR https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/pull/3938, you have, for javascript: https://github.com/gunadhya/vscode-docs/blob/9ba3b64b202229e05491d0af980ac70ca0aa5563/docs/languages/javascript.md#code-actions-on-save

Comment: It's great that there's an answer, but it doesn't seem to answer the main question: "Difference between codeActionsOnSave and formatOnSave in VS Code"?

Comment: @callum Good point. I have edited my answer to highlight the actual difference between the two.

Comment: @VonC nice! The difference in purpose is exactly what I was struggling to grasp. Your edit makes me get it now.

Comment: For people really particular, actual schema for `editor.codeActionOnSave`, showing it accepts an array, can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9b8548e4479c12e7f6e0e6023b63d660c3906225/src/vs/workbench/contrib/codeActions/browser/codeActionsContribution.ts#L27